# Internet Explorer not honoring max-width or max-height

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to use CSS to scale my images to precise values:

HTML:

```
<div id="thumbnail-container">
    <img src="sample-pic.jpg"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#thumbnail-container img {
    max-height: 230px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

In this example, `sample-pic.jpg` is actually 320x211.

In Firefox 11.0, this code works perfectly fine, and FF resizes `sample-pic.jpg` to the 230x211 max constraints set forth in the CSS rule.

In IE 9, however, the `max-height` and `max-width` rules are completely ignored and the image renders as its usual 320x211 size.

**How can I modify the HTML/CSS so that both IE 9 and FF 11.0 both honor these max constraints?** Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE7+ supports `max-width` and `max-height`.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/qE6w6/

check that you page runs in standards mode.. (*make sure there is a valid doctype*)

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you've declared a doctype and that there's NO output or whitespace before it. For example, this is HTML5's doctype and it should go at the very top of your output:

```
<!doctype html>
```

Also, if IE is in compatibility mode, that can cause problems. Try adding the following to your `<head>`:

```
<!-- Forces user OUT of IE's compatibility mode and removes "broken page" icon --> 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

**edit:** I was able to test, and it seems that no `doctype` *does* cause max-width not to work. Compatibility mode didn't seem to affect it (on this issue).