# @media queries not working in IE11 but working on Chrome/FF

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, responsive-design, media-queries

So I've been working on getting these wallboards for my company responsive. Thing is, with the css I've inserted it works brilliant on Chrome and FF. But nothing happens at all on IE, and they are going from FF to IE atm, so this has to work.

The code looks like this:

```
html, body {
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #8FAE9F;
            font-family: Trebuchet MS;
            font-size: 27px;
            font-weight: bold;
            height: 99%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .column.OBJ0, .column.OBJ1 { /* margin bruges til at mindske eller øge mellemrummet mellem overskrifterne */
            max-width: 12.0em;
            margin-right: -1.2em;
            margin-left: -1.2em;
        }
        .blueBorder, .thresholds {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 98%;
        }
        .thresholds {
            display: inline;
            float: left;
        }
        .Threshold_NONE {
            color: black;
        }
        .Threshold_INFO {
            color: green;
        }
        .Threshold_WARNING {
            color: yellow;
        }
        .Threshold_ALERT {
            color: red;
        }
        .Threshold_INFO, .Threshold_WARNING, .Threshold_ALERT, .Threshold_NONE {
            font-size: 5em;
        }
        .displayText {
        }
        .column {
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: text-top;
            line-height: normal;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        .header { /* max-height ændres hvis brugere skal tættere på overskrift */
            color: black;
            font-size: 3em;
            margin-left: -4px;
            margin-right: -4px;
            margin-top: -4px;
            max-height: 1em;
        }
        .columnwrapper {
            min-width: 378px;
            text-align: center;
            white-space: nowrap;
            width: 25%;
        }
        .displayAgent {
        }
        .displayAgent img {
            float: left;
            margin-bottom: auto;
            margin-right: 0.5em;
            margin-top: auto;
        }
        .displayAgent1 {
        }
        .displayAgent2 {
            background-color: #E6E6E6;
        }
        .displayAgentName {
            display: table;
            text-align: right;
        }
        .displayAgentStatusImg {
            padding-left: 0.5em;
        }
        .displayAgentStatus {
            display: inline;
            width: 71px;
        }
        .displayAgentStateTime {
            display: inline;
            width: 61px;
        }
        .displayAgentStatus_LoggedIn {
        }
        .displayAgentStatus_NotReady {
        }
        .displayAgentStatus_Ready {
        }
        .displayAgentStatus_Reserved {
        }
        .displayAgentStatus_LoggedOut {
        }
        .displayAgentStatus_Talking {
        }
        .displayAgentStatus_Working {
        }
        div .displayAgentStateTime {
            display: none;
        }
        div .displayAgentStatus {
            display: none;
        }
        .PoweredBy {
            bottom: 10px;
            display: none;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            padding: 5px;
            position: fixed;
            right: 10px;
        }
        .lastupdate {
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
            display: table;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            margin-top: 0;
            width: 7em;
        }
        .viewerDisplayItemErrorPanel {
            color: red;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .headline.remedyItem {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .remedyItem span {
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 1em;
            max-height: 1.2em;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        div.headline.remedyItem {
            text-align: center;
            border-bottom: 4px solid;
        }
        span.remedyId {
            width: 6em;
        }
        span.remedyCustomer {
            width: 6em;
        }
        span.remedyPriority {
            width: 2em;
        }
        span.remedyCaseTitle {
            text-align: left;
            width: 17em;
        }
        span.remedySLA {
            width: 5em;
        }
        span.remedySubSlaType {
            display: none;
        }
        span.remedyHidden {
        }
        span.remedyShowSLA {
            width: 4em;
        }
        span.remedyGroup {
            width: 6em;
        }
        div.column.Remedy {
            clear: left;
            margin-top: 0.5em;
        }
        div.column.Remedy h2 {
            display: none;
        }
        div.uccx_exchange_user span.exchangeStatus {
            display: none;
        }
        div.uccx_exchange_user span.uccxStatus {
            display: none;
        }
        div.uccx_exchange_user span.user { /* Desto højere width, desto mindre afstand mellem brugere horisontalt*/
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 1em;
            width: 3.9em;
        }
        div.uccx_exchange_user { /* Desto højere height, desto mere afstand mellem brugere vertikalt */
            max-height: 0.92em;
        }
        div.uccx_exchange_user img {
            margin-top: 0.2em;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .viewerDisplayItemShowPanel.øst { /* Dette påvirker øst brugeres position. */
            clear: right;
            float: right;
            text-align: left;
        }
        .viewerDisplayItemShowPanel.vest { /* Dette påvirker vest brugeres position. */
            clear: left;
            float: left;
            text-align: right;
            margin-left: 1.5em;
        }
        .viewerDisplayItemShowPanel.øst div img { /* Dette påvirker øst brugeres status position. */
            float: center;
            margin-left: -5.6em;
            margin-right: 0.0em;
        }
        .viewerDisplayItemShowPanel.vest div img { /* Dette påvirker vest brugeres status position. */
            float: center; 
            margin-left: -0.8em;
            margin-right: 0.1em;
        }

        .column h2.header { /* font-size ændres for at ændre gruppenavnets skriftstørrelse. */
            font-size: 1.7em;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .headline.remedyItem .remedyPriority {
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
            display: none;
        }
        .headline.remedyItem .remedyCustomer {
            margin-right: 3em;
        }
        span.NOT_SET {
            color: white;
        }
        div.FIX_AT_NONE .remedyId {
            color: yellow;
        }
        span.NORMAL_ALERT, span.FIX_AT_ALERT {
            color: red;
        }
        span.NORMAL_WARNING, span.FIX_AT_WARNING {
            color: yellow;
        }
        span.NONE_WARNING, span.NONE_NONE {
            color: blue;
        }
        span.NONE_ALERT {
            color: purple;
        }
        .BURNED {
            color: red;
        }
        .P1.remedyPriority {
            background-color: red;
        }
        .P2.remedyPriority {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        span.RESPECTED {
            color: green;
        }
        span.remedyUserLoginID {
            display: none;
        }
        span.penaltyOn {
            display: none;
        }
        @media all and (max-width: 1080px) {
            html, body {
                font-size: 20px;
            }}
        @media all and (max-width:800px) { 
/*  Dette smides ind til skalering. Alt der foregår i denne boks sker når skærmen     kommer under 640px. */
            html, body {
                font-size: 15px;
            }}
```

So what am I doing wrong? 
The program only allows me to enter css, not make extern css files or anything. Just one css file like this.

Thanks for your help in advice

Mikkel - The intern!

Comment: what is the meaning of not working? what is doing actually and what you expected?

Comment: Yeah I should have told that i suppose :) Well, what I am expecting it to be doing, is; as I make the window size smaller, i want everything to stay in the same spot, so basicly just the font being smaller. What it does on Chrome for instance, is exactly that, so everything stands as it should as I make the window size smaller. When doing so in IE, everything stays the same, so the components fall off the window as i make it smaller.

Comment: so `font-size:15px` is not applying when you view the site in 800px resolution. is it right?

Comment: Try @ media screen as well as or instead of @ media all as ie is a tard and this MAY be it, but I don't use all so can't be sure

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10287020/1540570

Comment: Exactly Suresh. That didn't change anything Carol, and I'm not entirely sure what to do with the link.

Comment: did you try with `!important`?

Comment: Not sure what that means, but we found out what the problem was. IE automaticly puts the intranet into compability mode, which caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Media Query work in IE-11 by this way:

```
@media all and (min-width: 1024px) {
    ... 
}
```

More details source [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: This doesn't work for me on IE when @media overrides other styiles.

Comment: Are you use in under all style ?
Because if you don't keep in the under or Bottom of all code it should be Overrides.